# Start snap-in chat with custom button

Tags: snap-ins

I'm trying to implement Snap-ins to replace existing contact/chat functionality. To make it as seamlessly as possible to users, I would like to use our existing chat buttons in our web application instead of the standard floating chat/contact us buttons. Is there an official way to do this?

Need to:

1. detect online/offline status to show Chat/Contact buttons accordingly.
2. When the Chat button is clicked, start a snap-in chat session.
3. When the Contact button is clicked, show the offline web-to-case form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was able to use own buttons to activate chat.

1. Add styles to hide standard buttons:

   > ```
   > .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton.helpButtonDisabled { display: none; }
   > .embeddedServiceHelpButton .helpButton .uiButton.helpButtonEnabled { display: none; }
   > ```
2. Add click listener to any chat buttons you want with class:

   > ```
   > const chatHandler = function() {
   >   if (typeof (<any>window).embedded_svc !== 'undefined') {
   >     (<any>window).embedded_svc.onHelpButtonClick();
   >   }
   > };
   > const els = document.getElementsByClassName('chat-button');
   > Array.prototype.forEach.call(els, function(el) {
   >   el.addEventListener('click', chatHandler);
   > });
   > ```

For detecting online/offline status to change buttons style, I ended up using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), creating a global observer for document looking for element with class **embeddedServiceHelpButton** and then creating an observer for any change in element with class **helpButtonLabel**. This element's text is changed by Salesforce Snap-ins when online/offline status changes.

Comment: can you please share also the mutationObserver code?

Comment: How do you operate within the `window` object when it's locked by the Locker Service? I am having trouble reaching `embedded_svc`. It would be great if you can elaborate on your answer!